# Gson. converting to JSON a password with the character =

Tags: android, gson

I'm using Gson in an Android app to convert a complicated object to JSON representation. One of the fields is a string called QuickPin containing an encrypted password and the character "=" is converted to "\003d" by Gson.

The Json string is consumed by a C# WEBAPI application, but returns "an error has occurred" message.

The following JSON returns that error message :

```
{"UserContractID":"929c1399-11c4-490e-8cff-5b1458ac18e2","UserAuthentication":"MethodCombo":{"AuthMethod":[1]},"QuickPin":"mW2n2uTECEtVqWA2B9MzvQ\u003d\u003d"},"CustomerID":0,"OriginID":0,"OriginTypeID":0,"Status":0}
```

Meanwhile this JSON works fine :

```
{"UserContractID":"929c1399-11c4-490e-8cff-5b1458ac18e2","UserAuthentication":{"QuickPin":"mW2n2uTECEtVqWA2B9MzvQ==","MethodCombo":{"AuthMethod":[1]}},"CustomerID":0,"OriginID":0,"OriginTypeID":0,"Status":0}
```

Are there a way to force Gson to maintain the string with the password with the = (and others if is the case) characters?

My Android code is :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
user = new User();
user.UserAuthentication = new UserAuthentication();
user.UserAuthentication.QuickPin = "mW2n2uTECEtVqWA2B9MzvQ==";
user.UserAuthentication.MethodCombo = new MethodCombo();
user.UserAuthentication.MethodCombo.AuthMethod = new ArrayList<Integer>();
user.UserAuthentication.MethodCombo.AuthMethod.add(1);
user.Status = 0;
String jsonRepresentation = gson.toJson(user);
object.put("user", jsonRepresentation);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gson escapes HTML metacharacters by default. [You can disable this behavior](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#disableHtmlEscaping%28%29).

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
```

Comment: Is what is contained in the set of "HTML metacharacters" widely known, or should you maybe list them in your answer? I am quite sure `<`, `>` and `&` are in there - common XML metacharacters which must be escaped), and [a random relevant page](http://javarevisited.blogspot.nl/2012/09/how-to-replace-escape-xml-special-characters-java-string.html) adds `'` and `"`. But the `=` is not.

Comment: `disableHtmlEscaping()` works and results in `=` after serialization.